# How to Receive US Dollars for my savings account

Tags: united-states, india, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

I'm Planning to open-up a small consulting firm in india. I need to know is there a way to open up an US bank’s account in my name in USA, without being physically present in US or   visiting US?

I'm having number of clients in USA to pay for my work, but I’m really confused to get money from my clients to my saving bank account.

I think that I'll be earning at least $5000 - $10000+ /month.(which is a Taxable income in India and will pay taxes)

Can anyone help me on this and I'm planning to get this started ASAP. And it should be 100% legal with perfect tax detection on my earnings.

Also suggest me with Banks that can help me to do so ?

Looking for your answers very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Opening Bank Account in US without physically being present is difficult.

> I'm having number of clients in USA to pay for my work, but I’m really confused to get money from my clients to my saving bank account.

You can get money via PayPal or if they are repeat customers, ask them to send via remittance services like Money2India or Remit2India etc.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot open an account in USA unless you have an address to provide to the bank in USA, You need ID, such as US Driver's License.

Comment: Not true. I once opened a bank account at Bank of America without USA ID and neither an address in USA. But I was physically present at the branch to open (and close) the account.